# Store int display Label ? Enum

Tags: python, pandas, enums

Is there a way in pandas data frame to store data in column as an integer, but when I print it on the screen to show a corresponding label instead.

Sort of like Enum map int <=> label

Comment: I think you can use [categorical data](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/categorical.html)

Answer (score 1):

Categorical data will do the job. thanks

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : ['c', 'b','f', 'e']})
 df.A.astype('category')
 df.A.cat.categories
 Index([u'b', u'c', u'e', u'f'], dtype='object')

 df.A.cat.codes

 0    1
 1    0
 2    3
 3    2
 dtype: int8
```

[memory usage](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/categorical.html#categorical-memory)